# My mails are filtered and delivered to Hotmail's JUNK mail folder

Tags: email, email-server, email-bounces

I've contacted Microsoft and filled in the JMRP, SNDS, and SenderID registration. Also I've put the correct SPF record on my server.

After several tests I note that emails containing plain text go to the Inbox, as well as HTML emails that include only text. If I make a HTML email with a hyperlink, it goes directly to the Junk folder.

Comment: There are a HUGE list of reasons why your mail will end up in a spam folder... everything from being put on a spam list (spamhaus) to mis-matching reverse-dns.  Without more information (like an actual email address) there's no more information I can provide.

Comment: Send you 2 headers of mails that i send. The first one is delivered to inbox, the second one to junk:

Comment: X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtTQ0w9Mw==
X-Message-Status: n
X-SID-PRA: responder-2011-04-10@cervecerafalkner.com
X-SID-Result: Pass
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-Message-Info: JGTYoYF78jGXXOQj1XErBNiacXmCmWImJCqcsfHHL+O2D7zDYh4oflnZgVPVScyF5OM8xc4wKqF2WYhbYw2SnGHwWM/ajNmESLgo0ZzLBok=
Received: from falkner.cervecerafalkner.com ([200.58.124.237]) by snt0-mc2-f13.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);
  Sun, 10 Apr 2011 17:07:02 -0700
Received: from falkner.cervecerafalkner.com ([200.58.124.237])
 by falkner.cervecerafalkner.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.63)

Comment: (envelope-from <responder-2011-04-10@cervecerafalkner.com>)
 id 1Q94ek-0003cy-3t
 for guillefalk@hotmail.com; Sun, 10 Apr 2011 21:07:02 -0300
Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2011 21:07:02 -0300 (ART)
From: responder-2011-04-10@cervecerafalkner.com
Reply-To: responder-2011-04-10@cervecerafalkner.com
To: guillefalk@hotmail.com
Message-ID: <32582734.0.1302480422027.JavaMail.root@falkner.cervecerafalkner.com>
Subject: Semana 30
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report

Comment: X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - falkner.cervecerafalkner.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - hotmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [0 0] / [502 502]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - cervecerafalkner.com
Return-Path: responder-2011-04-10@cervecerafalkner.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 11 Apr 2011 00:07:03.0348 (UTC) FILETIME=[62D98740:01CBF7DC]

hola

Comment: Send you the second message

Comment: X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtTQ0w9NA==
X-Message-Status: n
X-SID-PRA: responder-2011-04-03@cervecerafalkner.com
X-SID-Result: Pass
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-Message-Info: 6sSXyD95QpXw9d6uMMn0UPKn+RfZNnULH0dKCBUoNrzknquKq7cWmDurJIvpVBrwL9tNVkzhDRfUJLaGr4JAQ/merO7JMb3VrWzB1EzIZWI=
Received: from falkner.cervecerafalkner.com ([200.58.124.237]) by snt0-mc4-f13.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);
  Sun, 10 Apr 2011 15:03:02 -0700
Received: from falkner.cervecerafalkner.com ([200.58.124.237])
 by falkner.cervecerafalkner.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.63)

Comment: (envelope-from <responder-2011-04-03@cervecerafalkner.com>)
 id 1Q92ik-0004MA-4C
 for guillefalk@hotmail.com; Sun, 10 Apr 2011 19:03:02 -0300
Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2011 19:03:02 -0300 (ART)
From: responder-2011-04-03@cervecerafalkner.com
Reply-To: responder-2011-04-03@cervecerafalkner.com
To: guillefalk@hotmail.com
Message-ID: <9690857.0.1302472982096.JavaMail.root@falkner.cervecerafalkner.com>
Subject: Semana 22
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report

Comment: X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - falkner.cervecerafalkner.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - hotmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [0 0] / [502 502]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - cervecerafalkner.com
Return-Path: responder-2011-04-03@cervecerafalkner.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 10 Apr 2011 22:03:02.0898 (UTC) FILETIME=[0FFEF520:01CBF7CB]

<HTML>
<BODY>
  Si no desea seguir recibiendo nuestras comunicaciones haga click en el siguiente <a href="http://www.cervecerafalkner.com/beernews/unsuscribe.php?id=5445">link</a>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that your mailserver address appears to be a CNAME rather than an A record.  This is a violation of standards.  Change it to an A record with the same address as on the record the CNAME points to.

See my post on [Running an Email Server](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/running-an-email-server/) for some things to check.  My post on [Implementing DKIM](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-dkim-with-exim/) has references for some sites you can use to verify your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After you have verified the reverse DNS, Domain Key, Spamhaus blacklists etc I would also check the Spam score of the content of the email. The last step is often missed and can result in your mail landing in junk folder.